# Comparing lists by comparing values of elements of the list in Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and needed some help with part of a project. I am trying to compare which list is bigger between two lists of numbers, for example `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `[6,5,4,3,2,1]`. When the lengths of the lists are the same, I need to scan the lists from left to right comparing digit by digit. I thought to start with a for loop but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: sorry I need to know which number is greater between two numbers like 123,456 and 654,321 but these numbers have been put into lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're saying you basically need to compare and see if 123,456 is greater than 654,321?

You could make a function that accepts two input lists, like this:

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    first_number = int(''.join(str(x) for x in list1))
    second_number = int(''.join(str(x) for x in list2))
    if first_number > second_number:
        return first_number
    else:
        return second_number
```

This essentially converts each list into a string, and casts the list as an int, and then returns the larger int.

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem! If I helped I'd appreciate if you could mark the answer as correct :D

Answer (score 2):

you may  use the built-in function `max` with the parameter `key`:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1]

max([l1, l2], key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```

or you may use (suggested by @Ch3steR):

```
max(l1,l2,key=lambda x:(len(x),x))
```

Comment: `max(l1,l2,key=lambda x:(len(x),x))` since `max` signature is `max(*args,key)`.

Comment: Not a problem. ;) +1